# Moving apk to system/app. Operation failed

Tags: root-access, file-system, apk

I have rooted my Nexus 5 and am trying to move an apk to the system/apps directory but keep getting "Operation Failed". I am trying to move from the /data/app directory to the /system/app directory to give access to system only settings.

I have changed /system and /system/app to permissions of 777 with "Root Browser".

What needs to be changed to allow for this?

Comment: My answer: I had to remount by explicitly using `/system/bin/mount -o ...` rather than just `mount -o ...`. I'm guessing that at some point the version in /system/xbin started taking priority and for some reason that version fails silently. More info here: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/110883/109855

Answer (score 5):

Most devices have the `system` partition mounted as read-only. You need to remount the partition with write access so that you can modify the files.

[This free app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beansoft.mount_system) should work. Other utilities such as [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) and [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) also have the ability to remount the system partition as writeable.

Alternatively, you can use a [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) or ADB to run the following command, which should remount the volume as well.

`su`
`mount -o remount,rw /system /system`

After the volume is mounted as read/write, you can go ahead and move the app over. The volume will remain read/write until you reboot the device, at which time it will revert to read-only.

Answer (score 2):

Use ES File Explorer..

Select menu-> Switch on Root Explorer under Tools.

Again click on Root Explorer.

A pop up window will appear.

Select Mount R/W -> Select RW option from the new popup for '/' and 'system'.

Now onto your operation.
You will now be able to move the files without failure.