# Getting mount's usage suggestion when attempting /system remount

Tags: mount, command-line

I'm trying to remount system on a rooted Samsung GT-S6102 running Android 2.3.6:

```
# mount -o rw,remount,rw /system

Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory
```

This is exactly like in [this other answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110928/36875), so I'm not sure why I'm getting this usage error.

Answer (score 2):

So apparently the problem was that I needed to specify the target [as per the answer to this other question](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/60566/36875):

`mount -o remount,rw /system /system`