# How to copy ringtones to Galaxy Ace 2?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, ringtone, samsung-galaxy-ace-2

*Gingerbread on board :-).*

I try to customize ringtone, so I copied files to "/system/media/audio/ringtones". Depending on the app, either the copy is forbidden or the copy is ignored.

Next try -- as with Galaxy Ace, I created directory "/mnt/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones" and copied the files there. This worked, however Android does not pick them up when selecting audio for a ringtone.

When I first customized my phone (around 2 years ago) I used the app "Tone Picker" to help the system to select the customized audio, maybe something was changed in the app, I don't know, however this also does not work.

I would prefer to copy somehow the files without need of external application anyway.

So how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I try to customize ringtone, so I copied files to "/system/media/audio/ringtones". Depending on the app, either the copy is forbidden or the copy is ignored.

It is because system partition is always mounted in read-only mode by Android. To edit anything in that partition you'd have to remount the partition in read-write mode. And in order to remount the system partition you would need root privileges. Once you've them, see the answers for [Getting mount's usage suggestion when attempting /system remount](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/125433/96277) or [Can't remount /system in rw](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/60446/96277)

> I created directory "/mnt/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones" and copied the files there. This worked, however Android does not pick them up when selecting audio for a ringtone.

For some reason unbeknownst to me, if you move sound files into the Ringtones directory you would've to restart the Android in order to see those files as available ringtones through Settings app.

That however, is not the case if you use an app to set the ringtones.

Comment: Sure, no problem. :)