# Fire OS 5 mount -o remount,rw fails as root

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, mount

This is regarding Amazon's port of Lollipop. AFAICT, other similar questions are regarding Jelly Bean and earlier plus non deal with Fire OS.

I'm working with a rooted Amazon Fire TV/2 running Amazon's Fire OS 5, its Lollipop port. I'm unable as root to mount /system as r/w.

mount -o remount,rw /system fails with "mount: Invalid argument"

/dev/block/mmcblk0p13 is linked to /dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/by-name/system

/dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/by-name/system is mounted at /system

Mounting /system r/w (as root) worked fine under JB.

How can I remount /system as r/w under Amazon's Lollipop?

Comment: Have you tried the 2 argument version? `mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/by-name/system /system`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't remount /system in rw](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60446/cant-remount-system-in-rw)

Comment: Yes,  thanks I tried that with the same outcome. I also tried a remount using the /dev/block/mmcblk0p13 partition

Comment: And Firelord, this is not a duplicate. This is Amazon's port of Lollipop,  possibly a Linux SE kernel and all questions I've seen have been JB-related, thanks.

Answer (score -3):

You can also try with: mount -o rw,remount /system . For some devices this works fine.

```
root@angler:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
root@angler:/ #
root@angler:/ #
root@angler:/ #
root@angler:/ #
root@angler:/ #
root@angler:/ #
root@angler:/ #
root@angler:/ #
root@angler:/ #
root@angler:/ # mount -o remount, rw /system
root@angler:/ #
root@angler:/ #
root@angler:/ #
root@angler:/ #
root@angler:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
root@angler:/ #
root@angler:/ # getprop | grep build
[ro.bootimage.build.date]: [Fri May 6 06:19:55 EDT 2016]
[ro.bootimage.build.date.utc]: [1462529995]
[ro.bootimage.build.fingerprint]: [google/nexus_angler/angler:6.0.1/MTC19T/nate05060618:userdebug/test-keys]
[ro.build.characteristics]: [nosdcard]
[ro.build.date]: [Fri May  6 06:18:32 EDT 2016]
[ro.build.date.utc]: [1462529912]
[ro.build.description]: [angler-user 6.0.1 MTC19T 2741993 release-keys]
[ro.build.display.id]: [MTC19T]
```

I just did the test now on my device, Nexus 6P. As you see, both commands are valid and system applies them. Why was my answer down voted?

Comment: Why would changing the remount/rw to rw/remount would've any effect on the mount command? Ultimately, you're passing both the arguments in both the cases and you've not justified why interchanging the location of arguments  would've any effect on mount.

Comment: I dd'd the partition from a working copy and rebooted and mount -o remount,rw worked again. Later in the day I mounted system r/w and wrote to /system/xbin, then remounted ro. Immediately,  mount mails yet again. dd again and things are still working after 5 hours or so.  I'm leaning towards an Amazon port issue, but of course I'm guessing.

Comment: @Firelord, i cannot give a valid argument on why, but i am giving this info from my experience with Android. Seems some android device, random, did not work for me to mount the regular way. And i used this method. I will check my logs later tonight and come back with another reply.

Comment: Sure, I'll wait.