# Getting absolute path with "ls" command

Tags: shell, files

Is it possible to output the absolute file path when executing `ls -l` on Android (e.g. via `adb shell` or in a terminal app)?

Here is the output I get from `ls -l /etc/` (I have root access):

```
E:\Dropbox\Droid Explorer\src\main\resources\com\droid\explorer\adb>adb shell su root ls -l /etc/
-rw-r--r-- root     root        16656 2009-01-01 03:00 CHANGELOG-CM.txt
-rw-r--r-- root     root         9944 2009-01-01 03:00 CHANGES.txt
-rw-r--r-- root     root       154482 2009-01-01 03:00 NOTICE.html.gz
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2009-01-01 03:00 acdbdata
-rw-r--r-- root     root       598006 2009-01-01 03:00 apns-conf.xml
-rw-r--r-- root     root         5491 2009-01-01 03:00 audio_effects.conf
-rw-r--r-- root     root         6198 2009-01-01 03:00 audio_policy.conf
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2009-01-01 03:00 bash
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2009-01-01 03:00 bluetooth
-rw-r--r-- root     root       101774 2009-01-01 03:00 build-manifest.xml
-rw-r--r-- root     root         1045 2009-01-01 03:00 clatd.conf
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2009-01-01 03:00 dhcpcd
-rw-r--r-- root     root         1362 2009-01-01 03:00 ethertypes
-rw-r--r-- root     root        18300 2009-01-01 03:00 event-log-tags
-rw-r--r-- root     root        14309 2009-01-01 03:00 fallback_fonts.xml
```

What I would like to get is the absolute path, ex:

```
E:\Dropbox\Droid Explorer\src\main\resources\com\droid\explorer\adb>adb shell su root ls -l /etc/
-rw-r--r-- root     root        16656 2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/CHANGELOG-CM.txt
-rw-r--r-- root     root         9944 2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/CHANGES.txt
-rw-r--r-- root     root       154482 2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/NOTICE.html.gz
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/acdbdata
-rw-r--r-- root     root       598006 2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/apns-conf.xml
-rw-r--r-- root     root         5491 2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/audio_effects.conf
-rw-r--r-- root     root         6198 2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/audio_policy.conf
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/bash
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/bluetooth
-rw-r--r-- root     root       101774 2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/build-manifest.xml
-rw-r--r-- root     root         1045 2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/clatd.conf
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/dhcpcd
-rw-r--r-- root     root         1362 2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/ethertypes
-rw-r--r-- root     root        18300 2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/event-log-tags
-rw-r--r-- root     root        14309 2009-01-01 03:00 /etc/fallback_fonts.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` by default list everything supplied via argument. From `man ls`:

> -d, --directory
>                list directories themselves, not their contents
>
> -l     use a long listing format

So you can simly supply everything inside your targer directory, and give the option `-d`.

```
[adb shell] [su -c] ls -dl /etc/*
^ optional, depending on your shell environment
```

Which gives

```
rwxr--r-- 1 root root 1024 Jun 4 22:32 /etc/hosts
...
(and a lone list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Android is rooted, you can use any of the following commands:

```
# Replace DIR with the directory's path; prefix adb shell wherever appropriate.

su -c 'busybox ls -ld DIR*'  
su -c 'toybox ls -ld DIR*'
su -c 'ls -d DIR*'  # this does not work with long list format available through -l
```

<sub>(Courtesy of the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/242229) from An̲̳̳drew for listing the argument *-d*).</sub>

Android Marshmallow comes with Toybox. For any other Android version, you would need to setup [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) or [Toybox](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/130326/96277).

Example:

[image: IMG]

Comment: So I'm guessing the adb shell ls is limited. Dang I was hoping to do this without busybox. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a recursive list function in `sh` - this function can be copy-pasted in `adb shell`, without root permissions:

```
function rcrls() { ls -d $1/* | while read f; do echo "$f"; if [ -d "$f" ]; then rcrls "$f"; fi; done }
```

Then, use it as:

```
shell@myphone:/ $ rcrls /
```

Unfortunately, it will persist only for the current `adb shell` session, once you're out of it, you'll have to paste it again; or you can use it like this:

```
$ adb shell 'function rcrls() { ls -d $1/* | while read f; do echo "$f"; if [ -d "$f" ]; then rcrls "$f"; fi; done } ; rcrls /' | less
```

Then you can see files listed as:

```
...
//acct/uid/1000
//acct/uid/1000/cgroup.clone_children
//acct/uid/1000/cgroup.event_control
//acct/uid/1000/cgroup.procs
//acct/uid/1000/cpuacct.stat
//acct/uid/1000/cpuacct.usage
...
```

To get a listing with `-l` info, it's a bit tricky, since there's no working `sed` on `adb shell`; however, we can use string variable shell expansion and truncating to remove the basename from the listing, and then we can append the full path:

```
function rcrls() { 
  ls -d $1/* | while read f; do 
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then 
       fl="$(ls -ld $f/)"; 
       echo "${fl%\ *}" "$f"; 
       rcrls "$f"; 
    else 
       fl="$(ls -l $f)"; 
       echo "${fl%\ *}" "$f"; 
    fi; 
  done 
} ; 
rcrls /
```

Or, as one liner:

```
adb shell 'function rcrls() { ls -d $1/* | while read f; do if [ -d "$f" ]; then fl="$(ls -ld $f/)"; echo "${fl%\ *}" "$f"; rcrls "$f"; else fl="$(ls -l $f)"; echo "${fl%\ *}" "$f"; fi; done } ; rcrls /' | less
```

... and then you get a listing as:

```
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2017-11-15 02:29 //acct
-rw-r--r-- root     root            0 2017-11-15 02:29 //acct/cgroup.clone_children
--w--w--w- root     root            0 2017-11-15 02:29 //acct/cgroup.event_control
-rw-r--r-- root     root            0 2017-11-15 02:29 //acct/cgroup.procs
-r--r--r-- root     root            0 2017-11-15 02:29 //acct/cpuacct.stat
...
```