# I can't remount /system as rw. I get an error message: mount: Read-only file system

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, file-system, terminal, command-line, busybox

I'm using a rooted Huawei G7 and i'm trying to install BusyBox, but I keep getting an error. I'm 100% sure this error is because there is some weird write protection on `/system`. I know this because every time I try to change it to RW in ES File Explorer it changes back to RO when I close the app.

I also tried some terminal commands but with no luck so far.

EDIT: Here is the full log:

```
u0_a161@hwG7-L01:/ $ su
root@hwG7-L01:/ # mount
…
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
…
root@hwG7-L01:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
mount: Read-only file system
255|root@hwG7-L01:/ # mount
…
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
…
```

EDIT: When I try the mount command, I always get the error `Read-only file system`. I don't know why, but could it be possible to put `/system` in RW mode from the recovery menu?

Comment: Welcome to Android.SE!  We hope you'll like the place and decide to stay.  On a stock Android device, `/system` is normally mounted as "read-only".  This makes it more difficult for evil crackers and rogue apps to do Bad Things.  If you want to install BusyBox to `/system/xbin` — as you probably [should](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130313/where-should-i-install-toybox#131238) — you will need to temporarily remount it as "read-write" first.

Comment: First of all:  Is your device rooted?  Please [edit] your question and tell us.  Once you have done so, please flag this comment of mine as "obsolete", if you can do so.

Comment: Yes my device is rooted, i have tried to remount it as rw in es file explorer and i tried several terminal commands like su
mount -o rw,remount /system
cd /system
chmod -R -i *

Comment: Please type these four commands — `su` ; `mount` ;  `mount -o rw,remount /system` ; `mount` — and look carefully at the output.  Each `mount` command will produce a couple dozen lines of output. One of these lines will probably start with `/dev`, contain `/system` somewhere in it, and end with a digit, a space, and another digit. Please [edit] your question, add a heading labeled "EDIT:", and provide us with the relevant line of output from each `mount` command. Each time you edit your question, it will be bumped to the top of the homepage, which is good.

Comment: I edited the thread with a full log. I hope you can make sense of it. If not then feel free to ask for any other information

Comment: Your log is very hard to read, because Stack Exchange's Markdown parser has hidden all the linebreaks. Please [edit] the log and add one [backtick](http://enwp.org/backtick) at the very beginning of the log and one backtick at the very end. This should cause the linebreaks to become visible again. You can use the backtick key on your keyboard. If your keyboard for some reason doesn't include a backtick key, you can copy and paste some backticks in from Wikipedia.

Comment: Alright, i edited the log

Comment: OK, thank you. I proposed another edit to your question. Could you please click the [review link](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/145371) and click the "approve" button?  If you can.  I don't know if you can see the "approve" button, since you're a very new user here who has not yet racked up many reputation points.

Comment: I have approved the edit :)

Comment: I think you're running a compiled version of [toolbox/mount.c from kitkat-mr2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/kitkat-mr2-release/toolbox/mount.c), but I'm not 100% sure.  Could you please approve my latest edit, then add the output of the two-word command `mount help`? The command should output a one-line usage message which can help us to determine which `mount` you're running.

Comment: Just a note: did you see the `seclabel` flag in the output of `mount`? IMHO that indicates SELinux having its part in the game, and might prevent the partition from being remounted/altered. I've got no experience with this, but possibly SELinux must be either set to permissive mode first, or the remount command needs a specific additional parameter (`context=…`).

Comment: Maybe changing SELinux to permissive mode will help?  http://forums.androidcentral.com/optimus-v-rooting-roms-hacks/358572-rom-kernel-cm-11-0-4-4-4-os2sd-internal-f2fs-bigsuperrom-thunderc-4-4-4-a-61.html

Comment: But really, I don't know anything about SELinux, so I don't know whether or not permissive mode will help.  Please note also that changing SELinux to permissive mode may make your phone more vulnerable to all sorts of nefarious deeds done by nefarious software.

Comment: Any working answer for the above mentioned question ? Even i am facing same issue.