# How do I uninstall toybox (a busybox alternative)?

Tags: busybox, toybox

In my `/system/bin/` I have a executable named `toybox`, and various other directory entries in that directory symlinked to the `toybox`, eg `basename` and `[`.

How do I uninstall toybox?

Context: I believe it's messing with advanced root detection of Citi banking (my Revolut app is working just fine with Magisk's SafetyNet Fix)

Comment: Related: [Where should I install Toybox?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130313/where-should-i-install-toybox)

Comment: What have you tried? `mount -o rw,remount /system/bin; rm /system/bin/toybox`. Find all applets: `find /system/bin/ -type l -exec ls -l '{}' ';' | grep toybox` and delete them as well if you want. Also you can have another `toybox` in `/vendor/bin/`. Repeat the same for that too. But I won't advise this. Your device may get into bootloop because some core functions (including `init` services) depend on commands provided by `toybox`. Or at least put some alternative like `busybox` on `$PATH`. Also I'm not sure why you think it's messing with root detection.

Comment: And mind that `toybox` is not an uninstallable package. So you are  forcefully *deleting* it, not *uninstalling*.

Comment: *I believe it's messing with advanced root detection of Citi banking* -- what is the basis of your belief? The Android builds/devices certified by Google (that is to say, can be trusted for Google's own apps, banking, financial apps and so on) comes with toybox installed. If toybox was ever a factor in deciding whether an Android build is safe (not tampered with, nor rooted, etc.) than no banking or financial app would have continued to be offered on Play Store (their developers would have packed up and moved on).