# How to move/delete Toybox executable and its symlinks properly?

Tags: toybox, symlink

Have a Chainfire-rooted Samsung Galaxy J5 with Android 7.1.
Busybox 1.34.1 in `/system/xbin`, and Toybox (unfortunately) in `/system/bin` (installed by: "`toybox | toybox sed 's/\ /\n/g'| toybox sed '$d'| while read line; do toybox ln -sf /system/bin/toybox /system/bin/$line; done)`".

How to move (or delete) them properly?

I did it with Total Commander 'search' for 'toybox' string (as it should be in symlinks?) and then move them (just like in Windows). But I think it was bad, as I run into fs problems. Symlinks were not "really" deleted and the "moved" ones were "converted" into files (of same size, ~273k).

Comment: [How do I uninstall toybox?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248877/how-do-i-uninstall-toybox-a-busybox-alternative#comment334753_248877).

Comment: Thanks for the link! Useful.