# push entire folder with ADB

Tags: adb

By mistake I deleted the .EXT folder (which contains a file "su") from the system/bin folder of my Android device.
Is it possible to use ADB to replace this folder?
I have a copy of the Bin folder and would like to Push this to my Android device with ADB push or ADB sideloader.

Answer (score 4):

let's say you want to push entire C:\framework dir into /system/framework

put yourself in parent dir C:

```
adb push framework /system/
```

done

framework dir will be created automatically, so don't enter i.e. "adb push framework /system/framework/" or it will create a framework subdir

also assume `adb` is in path

of course you need read write permission, so in case of read only /system precede

```
adb remount
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one file in that directory so you can rather do this:

```
adb shell su -c mount -o rw,remount /system  # remounts the system partition in read-write mode
adb shell su -c mkdir /system/bin/.ext       # creates the directory .ext under /system/bin/
adb push LOCAL_PATH/.su /system/bin/.ext/    # replace LOCAL_PATH with the path where your .su file resides in PC
```

If you still insist on pushing the folder, then create a  new directory in PC and move `.ext` directory inside it. (We're doing this because adb pushes only the content of a directory). Afterwards, do:

```
adb shell su -c mount -o rw,remount /system
adb push LOCAL_PATH/NEW_DIR /system/bin/   # LOCAL_PATH/NEW_DIR is the path to the new directory you just made in PC
```

For both the cases: it appears that directory has full read-write permission from everyone, given the attributes `rwxrwxrwx`. However, make sure to change the attributes for `.su` to `rwxr-xr-w`. Do:

```
adb shell su -c chmod 755 /system/bin/.ext/.su
```

See [Can't remount /system in rw](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/60446/96277) if my remounting instruction doesn't work.