# Why can I write to a read-only system partition?

Tags: permissions, mount, system, busybox

I have a rooted phone running android 4.4. When I check the output of 'mount' it says system is read only. My root file manager or terminal can't make any files or folders there, though only the file manager shows an error occured.

But I found I am able to copy files from my data partition to system, even overwriting system files if I want to. Why is this?

Another odd thing I noticed is that the system applets like mount and mkdir are actually symlinks to a binary file called 'toolbox'. For some reason I am not able to remount the system partion with the normal syntax, it says invalid option (using -o remount,rw /dev/xxx/system /system). This is preventing me from installing busybox with an installer app.

Comment: toolbox is not an odd thing. It is normal for Android.Anyhow, for remount issue, follow [Can't remount /system in rw](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/60446).

Comment: I saw that thread, it was not helpful. I tried all syntax variations, but it says invalid option.

Comment: after installing new firmware I was able to remount system like normal. But the odd possibility to write to a RO partition remains. OS is Flyme (from Meizu).